# Rails ActiveRecord_Relation globally available available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, permissions, global-variables

In my User model, I have some relationships:

```
has_many :properties
has_many :roles, through: :properties
```

At many places in my application, in special at the Navbar, the menus are shown to the user if they have a specific 'property' and 'role'. To check these permissions, for each item in the navbar I need to check the User model and it's relationships. But this executes many queries to the DB and I want to avoid it.

My idea is to use a variable ('user_permissions') that is the response for the query that contains all necessary details about the user.

How can I call this query only once in the application and save this information in a variable (until I force a 'reload' for this variable) that is accessible in all controllers and views?

Comment: I suggest you to check the gem [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) on Github.

Comment: Check this [list](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) of Ruby on Rails gems related to authorization and permissions.

Comment: I will check these gems. Thanks for the ideas, but is there a gem-less solution?